# Error in Xcode when run react-native app on iPod Touch

Tags: xcode, react-native

I try run my react-native app on me old MacBook with Xcode version 10.1 and on my iPod Touch, and all build successfully, but when app starts, I have some Error in Xcode `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)`
and `dyld: Symbol not found: _UITextContentTypeAddressCity Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/87E9DD90-EA14-4C01-879D-BDBA2E257A1F/skilla.app/skilla Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/87E9DD90-EA14-4C01-879D-BDBA2E257A1F/skilla.app/skilla`

And the screen goes black on mine iPod. With what it can be connected? How can I solve this issue?